# How can I avoid returning a Task<Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit> from an F# library

Tags: c#, .net, f#, interop, clr

When wrapping an asynchronous operation in F# with Async.StartAsTask the returned type will be of `Task<unit>`. This makes users of an interface depend on the F# core libraries. Is there a recommended practice to avoid this, or is it generally the accepted behaviour to leave it at it's default?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply upcast the `Task<Unit>` to a `Task` as you don't need the access to the generic result.

E.g.

```
let taskOfUnit = asyncOfUnit |> Async.StartAsTask
taskOfUnit :> Task
```